# Number of Outside Roots of a Polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Consider the following polynomial
$$P(z)=\frac{(z-a)(1-az)}{bz}+Q(z),\quad \text{with}\;a\in(0,1)\; \text{and}\;b\in \mathbb R_+,$$
and with
$$Q(z)=1-c z^{-1} - d z,\quad \text{with}\;c,d\in\mathbb R.$$

Suppose that $Q(z)$ has one root satisfying $|z|>1$. Under which conditions can I guarantee that $P(z)$ has two roots satisfying $|z|>1.$?

My guess is that $Q(a^{-1})>0$ would be sufficient, but have not been able to prove it.

---

A related result: If $Q(a^{-1})>0$ and $d=0$, I can show that $P(z)$ has one root satisfying $|z|>1$ with the following argument:

First notice that $P(a^{-1})=Q(a^{-1})>0$. Next, notice that the coefficient of highest order of $P(z)$ is $-a/b$ so that for $z$ high enough $P(z)<0$. It follows that there is a root of $P(z)$ bigger than $a^{-1}>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I missed something $P(z)=0$ is equivalent to a quadratic equation $z^2+pz+q=0$ with real coefficients. Therefore we can check two cases: If $P(z)$ has no real root ($p^2 -4q <0$) the root condition $|z|>1$ is equivalent to $|q|>1$. If $P(z)$ has two real roots you should get another not to complicated formula (Sorry, I'm a little lazy for the second case).

Supplement: The numerator of $P(z)=0$ can be linear for $a+bd=0$.

Comment: I'm actually interested in the case with more complicated $Q(z)$ with higher orders. In simplifying I rendered it kind of trivial by mistake. Still, I think it will be useful to better understand this simpler case. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I posted a new question here if you are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4125023/287326