# Outside Roots of a Polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Consider the following polynomial
$$P(z)=\frac{(z-a)(1-az)}{bz}+Q(z),\quad \text{with}\;a\in(0,1)\; \text{and}\;b\in \mathbb R_+,$$
and with
$$Q(z)=1-\sum_{i={-n}}^m c_i z^{i},\quad \text{with}\;c_i\in\mathbb R\;\text{for all }i.$$

Suppose that $Q(z)$ has $m$ roots satisfying $|z|>1$. Under which conditions can I guarantee that $P(z)$ has $m+1$ roots satisfying $|z|>1.$?

My guess is that $Q(a^{-1})>0$ would be sufficient, but have not been able to prove it.

---

A related result: If $Q(a^{-1})>0$ and $m=0$, I can show that $P(z)$ has one root satisfying $|z|>1$ with the following argument:

First notice that $P(a^{-1})=Q(a^{-1})>0$. Next, notice that the coefficient of highest order of $P(z)$ is $-a/b$ so that for $z$ high enough $P(z)<0$. It follows that there is a root of $P(z)$ bigger than $a^{-1}>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**
I'd like to see some broader contest of the problem. I think there are some relevant pieces of the picture missing.

**Assessing the problem** (This is rather an opinion and some guessing what I would do).
$b$ and "$1-$" of $Q(z)$ can be condensed to a condition on $c_0$. Changing the variable $w=z^{-1}$ changes the root condition to the unit disc. This provides easy access to "Schwarz Lemma", "Rouche's Theorem" and maybe others that could be useful. Alltogether we get a polynomial equation like
$$ w^mP(w) = w^{m+1}(w-a)(1-aw) + \sum_{k=0}^{m+n} d_k w^k = 0$$
$w^{m+1}(w-a)(1-aw)$ has $m+2$ roots in the unit disc whereby $w^{m+1} =0$ corresponds to $z=\infty$. This needs some care for counting roots with $|z|>1$. How the Sum $\sum_{k=0}^{m+n} d_k w^k$ distorts the roots depends basically on values it takes on the boundary of the unit disc (Rouche's theorem).

For $|w|=1$ we get $|w^{m+1}(w-a)(1-aw)|=|(w-a)(1-aw)|$. At least one part of Rouche is not to bad. Evaluating $\left|\sum_{k=0}^{m+n} d_k w^k\right|$ depends on the conditions you want to impose.

Answer (score 1):

To see that the condition $Q(a^{-1}) > 0$ is not sufficient, let
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
&n=0,\,m=1\\[4pt]
&a=\frac{2}{3},\,b=1\\[4pt]
&c_0=c_1=\frac{1}{3}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
Then $Q(z)$ simplifies to
$$
\frac{2-z}{3}
$$
which has $z=2$ as its only root, and
$$
Q(a^{-1})=Q\Bigl(\frac{3}{2}\Bigr)=\frac{1}{6} > 0
$$
and $P(z)$ simplifies to
$$
\frac{-9z^2+19z-6}{9z}
$$
which has two roots, but only one of them has absolute value greater than $1$.